# Changing a light switch

Tags: switch, light

I am trying to change an old light switch. It only operates a light, so I believe it is a simple, two way switch. Current switch has a black wire pinned into the back of the switch, a black wire that is on the screw, and a red switch also on the screw. I am changing this to a simple DeCora paddle switch. Which wires go where?

Comment: `black wire that is on the screw` ... what screw? ... `black wire pinned into the back of the switch` ... how? ... where? ... please post clear, well lit, closeup pictures

Comment: please read what you wrote

Comment: Hi Ingrid, electricity is dangerous and no one wants to guess and cause any harm. Photos would clarify things.

Comment: @josotola,  I think she was eluding to a  black wire "backstabbed"  a black wire under a screw and a red WIRE under a screw.  But still pics are needed

Comment: just wire the new like the old

Comment: @RMDman - That’s exactly what I meant. My apologies as this is my first time posting. I can’t seem to upload the pictures. I have a black wire backstabbed at the top of the switch, a red wire backstabbed at the bottom of the switch, and another black wire under the top, side screw.